# onclick not working for few anchor tags

Tags: javascript

I have few identical anchor tags. But one of them is not working as expected.

I have hosted the content [here](http://liveweave.com/B1qnYn)

Any help would be appreciated

**Edit - Added code to question:**

```
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1) " style=" text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
```

*the spaces actually represent some kind of non-printing character that ended up being the root of the op's issue.*

Comment: Please include the snippets of code relevant to your problem in your question.

Comment: for some reason the editor on the website is not working properly. try coding it in a text editor(locally) and paste it in there.

Comment: http://liveweave.com/9nJowi working

Comment: Your error could be detected if you used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: The fourth anchor has a hidden character lurking just before the words "text-decoration" that is causing the code to break. You can see this if you copy and paste the text into the browser console. If you just copy the text from one of the other anchors to that one it will work.

Comment: @bhargav I tried it in my notepad++ too, It did not work as expected

Comment: There's a couple of non-printing characters in there. The validator detects them and complains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some weird hidden characters in that line of HTML. specifically, before the closing `"` of the `onclick` and after the opening `"` of the `style`.

You can fine them if you move through the line of HTML with the right arrow key.

Here is your HTML pasted into a simple word processor:

```
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1) " style=" text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
<a onclick="alert(1)" style="text-decoration: underline;">111</a>
```

Comment: Absolutely great answer

Comment: @myname glad to help. small 'difficult to detect' issues like this can be super frustrating.

Comment: I spent 4 hours on this. Furthermore, i asked the same question before and it got downvoted badly and then removed.. I hate SO